# How to create a java batch file from Intellij IDEA project (Selenium and TestNG)

Tags: java, batch-file, jenkins, testng

I wanna create a executable batch file to run my project without an IDE. File hierarchy is given below. 
*I use Intellij IDEA
[image]

Comment: Note: just in case, make sure the source folder is in lowercase: `src`, not `Src`.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to find the right command line to type in order to execute your testng tests.

If you can configure your `pom.xml` in order for a `mvn clean test` to work, you can adapt it in a Jenkins job.

---

See "[TestNG Maven plug-ins](http://testng.org/doc/maven.html)", in order for your `pom.xml` to include the right plugins.
For selenium, you can follow the tutorial "[Maven & Jenkins with Selenium](https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html)"
Your dependencies should include:

```
    <dependency>                
         <groupId>junit</groupId>                               
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>                             
         <version>3.8.1</version>                               
         <scope>test</scope>                                
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>                              
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>                              
        <version>2.45.0</version>                               
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>                               
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>                             
        <version>6.8</version>                              
        <scope>test</scope>                                     
   </dependency>
```

---

Then a simple Jenkins maven job with a `clean test` target should be enough:

[image: https://cdn.guru99.com/images/5-2015/050115_1023_MavenJenkin27.jpg]